# How to include wanrings and notices in Zend Framework error controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have implemented ZF error controller which will notify via email when something goes wrong but not when some warnings or notices occur. I'm trying to achieve same when a warning or notice is occurred. In ZFDebug it's showing warning and notices. I would like to get notification email for the same.

[image]

I have tried setting following but not working

```
Bootstart.php and index.php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

Application.ini

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
phpSettings.auto_detect_line_endings = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to define your own error handler somewhere in your Bootstrap.php (not tested):

```
public function noticeErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
    // This error code is not included in error_reporting
    return false;
}

$errorMsg = 'In file '.$errfile.' on line '.$errline.': '.$errno.' - '.$errstr;

mail('xxx@geekpub.de', 'Error in application', $errorMsg);
exit;
}
set_error_handler("noticeErrorHandler");
```

Comment: It seems the warnings and errors gets suppressed after 

$application->bootstrap()->run();

I'm able to set_error_handler("var_dump") before the bootstrap run.
On index.php top I have set
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);